# SpriteRenderer shrinks after copying it's texture

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, texture2d

I have a SpriteRenderer with a texture, and I want to make a copy of the texture and assign this copy to the same SpriteRenderer

```c#
//Copy of the texture that will be changes in runtime
[HideInInspector]
public Texture2D tempTexture;
//FilterMode of the copied texture
[SerializeField]
private FilterMode filterMode = FilterMode.Bilinear;

/// <summary>
/// Create a copy of the texture that is used by a SpriteRenderer and unload the original texture from the memory
/// </summary>
void Start()
{
    var spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    if(spriteRenderer==null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("SpriteRenderer is null");
        return;
    }
    var tex = spriteRenderer.sprite.texture;
    if (tex == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Sprite's texture is null");
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log("original texture size is: " + tex.width + " : " + tex.height);

    tempTexture = new Texture2D(tex.width, tex.height, tex.format, false);
    tempTexture.filterMode = filterMode;
    try
    {
        var colors = tex.GetPixels();
        tempTexture.SetPixels(colors);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.LogError(ex.Message);
        return;
    }
    tempTexture.Apply();
    Resources.UnloadAsset(tex);
    spriteRenderer.sprite = Sprite.Create(tempTexture, spriteRenderer.sprite.textureRect, Vector2.one * 0.5f);
}
```

It I don't change texture's size (or make it bigger) in the Inspector by overriding it everything works perfect. But if I make the size of the texture smaller, then the sprite shrinks when my script completed its job.

One more time. If the texture has size, let's say, bigger than 512x512, and I change it to 512 in the Inspector, then the sprite shrinks and becomes two times smaller.

The problem is in my script, because if I disable it - everything is okay, even if i override the texture's size.

Any ideas about how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

```
var oldSprite = spriteRenderer.sprite;
spriteRenderer.sprite = Sprite.Create(tempTexture, spriteRenderer.sprite.textureRect, Vector2.one * 0.5f, oldSprite.pixelsPerUnit, 0, SpriteMeshType.Tight, oldSprite.border);
```

`border` property of the sprite is responsible for its size